# Any way to get name of current lambda function within boto3 without specifying the name?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

The below mentioned name is my lambda function name.

I need to get the same name inorder to use it in the s3 path for csv file. Instead of hardcoding/manually writing the filename(**pending_record.csv**).

I need to get the name from lambda function name without metric_ and need to use it as my file name.

Example:

**lambda function name:**

```
metric_pending_record
```

**S3 path:**

```
s3_path='centriam/b2c/metric_result/pending_record.csv'
```

I tried the below approach:

```
print("Lambda function name:", context.function_name)
```

It will give:

```
metric_pending_record
```

but not sure how can I remove `metric_` and use it as file name.

Is there any way to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If it's always "metric_pending_record" then you know in advance that the result is going to be "pending_record". If it's not always "metric_pending_record" then you presumably want to parse a specific pattern. Is the pattern always going to be "abc_xyz..." where you want the results to be "xyz..."?

Answer (score 1):

This will extract the portion after the first underscore:

```py
name = 'metric_pending_record'
suffix = name[name.find('_')+1:]
print(suffix)
```

Or, for the more Pythonic (and confusing) way:

```py
name = 'metric_pending_record'
suffix = '_'.join(name.split('_')[1:])
print(suffix)
```